# Find out who's bringing in child dependency on first npm install

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

I'm trying to run `npm install` on a legacy project. It breaks with a fairly obscure error, coming from a child dependency which fails to install.

Trying to find out which of my dependencies brought in the child dependency, I ran `npm ls [child-dep]`, but `ls` seems to only work once the packages are already installed.

Yes, I could start removing dependencies batch-wise, narrowing it down to the responsible one step by step. But I'm hoping there's a more straightforward way.

How can I find out which dependency is trying to install a certain child dependency before there is a node_modules folder?

Comment: I don't think there's any automated way. Do you have a lockfile?

Comment: Nope, sadly not :(